# PHP ping allways return active state

Tags: php, laravel, ping

Hello I've enountered a problem when trying to ping IP adresses. Script allways returned that IP is active although I know that these IP are not active.
I don't really know if my logic is bad or pinging script is badly written.
Thank you in advance.
Here's what i 've got:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Ping;

class ping_controller extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function ping()
    {
        $ipcount = Ping::count();
        $ip =[];
        $i = 1;

        for($i = 1; $i <= $ipcount; $i++)
        {
            $ip[$i] = Ping::where('id',$i)->pluck('ip_adress');
            $newip = str_replace('["', '', $ip[$i]);
            $newip2 = str_replace('"]', '', $newip);
            exec("ping -n 1 " . $newip2 . " | head -n 2 | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $7}'", $ping);
            $ping_time = implode("", $ping);
            if($ping_time<=1000)
            {
                $status[$i] = "PC $newip2 is active";
            }
            else
            {
                $status[$i] = "PC $newip2 is inactive";
            }
        }
    $on = implode(" , ",$status);
    return view("/home")->with("status", $on);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have to deal with the last parameter of *exec* function like this:

```
exec("ping -c 1 localhost", $output, $result)
```

according to [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php):

> **string exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )**
>
> return_var
>
> If the return_var argument is present along with the output argument,
>   then the return status of the executed command will be written to this
>   variable.

so you have to check $result variable whether it's 0 or 1:

0 -> success

1 -> otherwise

so this:

```
            exec("ping -c 1 " . $newip2, $ping, $result);
            if($result == 0)
            {
                $status[$i] = "PC $newip2 is active";
            }
            else
            {
                $status[$i] = "PC $newip2 is inactive";
            }
```

instead of:

```
            exec("ping -c 1 " . $newip2 . " | head -n 2 | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $7}'", $ping);
            $ping_time = implode("", $ping);
            if($ping_time<=1000)
            {
                $status[$i] = "PC $newip2 is active";
            }
            else
            {
                $status[$i] = "PC $newip2 is inactive";
            }
```

Comment: One thing has changed. Now it's showing all inactive. I tried ping my own local ip and result was still inactive.

Comment: maybe it's: 

`exec("ping -c 1 " . $newip2, $ping, $result);`

so -c instead of -n??

Comment: please, mark it as solved if it works fine @JakubSkurčák

Comment: I tried -c and -n but allways it returns all active or inactive depends on if it's -c or -n